# Simple KeyListener not working

Tags: java, swing, jframe, keylistener

I'm working on a really simple project in Java to try to understand how to use KeyListener. 
I've created a Main class and a KeyListener, MouseListener class. I want to get something to happen when I press a keyboard key. So far the only thing that is working is "Hello" when I click.

Here is my code:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class KeyPractice{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();

        panel.addKeyListener(new KeyEar());
        panel.addMouseListener(new KeyEar());

        frame.add(panel);

        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(400, 400);
    } 
}
```

And the Keylistener class....

```
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

public class KeyEar implements KeyListener, MouseListener {

    public KeyEar(){

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0) {
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `JPanel` cannot gain focus for `KeyListener` to work.

The preferred approach is to use [Key Bindings](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) for Swing. You can map an Action to a KeyStroke even when a component doesn't have focus.

[Key Binding Example](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/10/key-bindings/)

Answer (score 5):

- [JPanel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/panel.html) isn't focusable [JComponent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/index.html), have to add `Object`/`JComponents` that is focusable or interact with `KeyEvents`
- [KeyListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html) isn't proper [listener for Swing JComponents](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/index.html), for Swing is replaced with [KeyBindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)

Comment: @Imray: The tutorial cited inlcude numerous examples.

Answer (score -1):

I had similar problem but its so simple to solve but you have to found how to solve it witch is not so easy task :D

so how to solve this ? I just set all my buttons as focusable false.
        `instanceOfYourButton.setFocusable(false);` 
thats it